# Text Property of `initial-scratch-message' Not Taking Effect

Tags: font-lock, text-properties, scratch-buffer

```lisp
;;; ~/.emacs.d/init.el

(custom-set-variables
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(initial-scratch-message #("++"
                             0 2 (face underline))))
```

I expect to see an underscore in `*scratch*`, but it's not there.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `face` to `font-lock-face` in order for `font-lock-mode` to handle that.

If `font-lock-mode` was disabled then your original approach would work, but when it's enabled (which it is by default) you need to work with it so that it doesn't clobber pre-existing faces.

Comment: If I change `"++"` to `";+"`, it doesn't work.  It seems that `";+"` will use the face for *comment*.  How to prevent this?

Comment: Makes sense -- if you insert a comment into the buffer, you can expect it to be fontified as a comment.  I'm not sure if there's a trivial way to underline text other than via the face property.  You can disable font-lock-mode for the buffer, but that obviously has other consequences.  Otherwise, looking at `(elisp)Displaying Faces` suggests that an overlay might be an option for you.  Or you can fake an underline via composition of glyphs: `(insert (mapconcat (lambda (char) (compose-string (concat (char-to-string char) "_"))) "; foo" ""))` (experimental; there might be a cleaner way).